# Stylesheet does not work with special characters pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

```
Could not parse stylesheet of object 0x2d956381ba0
```

[image]

```
   def change_btn_image(self, btn):
    imagem = self.atv_imagens_bd[self.atividades.get_contador()]
    nome_imagem = imagem[:-4]
    print(nome_imagem)

    btn.setStyleSheet(f"border-image: url(src/main/resources/base/{imagem});")
    return nome_imagem
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: When the name of the pushButton background image in the stylesheet has a special "ÃÉ" type character, this error occurs. 
 `btn.setStyleSheet(f"border-image: url(src/main/resources/base/PÃO.png);")`

Comment: Use quotes around the path: `btn.setStyleSheet(f"border-image: url('src/main/resources/base/{imagem}');")`

Comment: @musicamante if you can answer the question so I can put your answer as correct, because it worked: D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in a [slightly related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66682716/2001654), HTML (and, therefore, stylesheet) parsing capabilities of Qt are a bit limited if compared to web browser parsers.

While those syntax are somehow pretty "liberal", one shouldn't push the boundaries of their *freedom* too much: it's always good practice to use quotes for string based values (besides keywords, obviously), most importantly for URLs.

In this case, the problem is the utf character, which creates a problem as the parser is unable to correctly identify where the url ends.

Just add quotes around the url path:

```
btn.setStyleSheet(f"border-image: url('src/main/resources/base/{imagem}');")
```